# 400 Bad Request from google

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, https

Every time when I try to pull google.com it just responds with 400 Bad Request. Tried changing to \n\n to \r\n but still the same problem. Since its HTTP error, I assume there is no problem with the sockets.

```
import socket
import ssl

socks = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
SSLSocks = ssl.wrap_socket(socks)
ip = socket.gethostbyname('google.com')
request = "GET / HTTPS/1.1\n"
request += "Host: " + ip + "\n\n"
#request += "Content-Type: application/json\r\n"
#request += "Connection: close"+"\r\n"

SSLSocks.connect((ip,443))
SSLSocks.send(request.encode())
result = SSLSocks.recv(4096)
print(ip)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
172.217.163.142
b'HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\nReferrer-Policy: no-referrer\r\nContent-Length: 1555\r\nDate: Tue, 22 Jan 2019 12:28:37 GMT\r\n\r\n<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=en>\n  <meta charset=utf-8>\n  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">\n  <title>Error 400 (Bad Request)!!1</title>\n  <style>\n    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/br'
```

Comment: why not use a standard library like `requests`?  it would make sure you're sending a valid HTTP request…

Comment: @SamMason Later, I will port all of this to an embedded device running micro python. So I am trying to avoid any library which will spike the code size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to fix your code:

1. the protocol is still `HTTP`
2. you need to terminate every line with `\r\n`

also context managers help a lot and seem to be mostly supported by micropython

```
import socket
import ssl

host = 'www.google.com'

request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n"
request += "Host: " + host + "\r\n"
request += "Content-Type: application/json\r\n"
request += "Connection: close\r\n"
request += "\r\n"

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
    sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock)
    sock.connect((host, 443))
    peer = sock.getpeername()
    sock.send(request.encode())
    result = sock.recv(4096)
    sock.close()

print(peer)
print(result)
```

Comment: I didn't understand. why is it still http when we are using port 443 and wrap_socket? The above code gives me a 301 moved permanently.

Comment: you want the `host` to be the redirect target…  will update the answer

Comment: Thank you, Sam. Now everything is fine.